# RETURNURL from a secure token

Tags: paypal

I am using a secure token on the payflow link.  I successfully create a token with the values of the following.

```
    setupParameters.put("CANCELURL", "http://localhost:9090/paypalcancel");
    setupParameters.put("ERRORURL", "http://localhost:9090/paypalerror");
    setupParameters.put("RETURNURL", "http://localhost:9090/paypalcompleted");
    setupParameters.put("URLMETHOD", "POST");
    setupParameters.put("TEMPLATE", "TEMPLATEB");
    setupParameters.put("DISABLERECEIPT", "TRUE");
```

It looks like the RETURNURL is working, but it is redirecting to the url below.
https://payflowlink.paypal.com/http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9090%2Fpaypalcompleted

Which gives me this http error HTTP Error 404 - File not found.
No surprise because it is not hitting my url. ("http://localhost:9090/paypalcompleted")

What am I missing here?

Thanks in Advance,

Paul

Comment: Have you tried on a public server? I believe you cannot test this further using a local server.

Comment: I haven't.  If I used the RETURNURL from the setup page in the manager and did not override it...it worked.  It is the overriding it that messes it up.

Answer (score 0):

OK,

So the problem was with using the HTTPClient from Apache.  It must have been URLEncoding the parameters.  I switched to use the the standard java URL connection, it worked fine.  I just had to make the parameter string by hand.

```
        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

        String urlParameters = "";
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        if(setupParameters!=null) {
            for(String key : setupParameters.keySet()) {
                sb.append(key+"="+setupParameters.get(key)+"&");
            }
        }
        urlParameters=sb.toString().substring(0, sb.toString().length()-1);
        // Send post request
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();

        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
```